# New components config does not show up?

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, esp-idf

I'm using VSCode with the ESP-IDF extension. My problem is: I simply can not get the configuration GUI (F1 -> ESP-IDF: SDK Configuration editor (menuconfig)) to update itself so that any newly added components configurations are shown.
When I execute `idf.py.exe menuconfig` in the terminal, then the menu items show the newly added component but not in the extensions GUI.

Is there any possibility to update the configuration GUI on request?

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I've encountered the same where menuconfig would not reflect changes to Kconfig (or to adding Kconfig.projbuild).  I had to exit VScode and re-start for the menuconfig to reflect the changes.